# How to solve route nullable peremeter problem

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-routing

here is my route:

```
Route::get('statement/{month?}/{userid?}', 'UserController@statement');
```

The problem is there $month or $user_id may or not may be. If $user_id found and $month not found so the $user_id happens the first peremeter naturally. But first peremeter is $month. So it will return me wrong report.

here is my controller method:

```
public function statement($month = null, $user_id = null){}
```

here is my menu anchor tag:

```
<a href="{{ route('user.statement', [$month, $user]) }}">
   statement
</a>
```

how do i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could recieved `month` and `user_id` using query parameter in get method or in Body using post method. Then you will be able to recieved them in request.

```
Route::get('statement', 'UserController@statement');
```

or

```
Route::post('statement', 'UserController@statement');
```

And in controller

```
public function statement(Request $request){
     $month = $request->month;
     $user_id = $request->user_id

}
```

Comment: I called this from anchor tag. so how to form request work here?

Comment: use get method then..```base_url/statement?month=value&user_id=value```

Comment: month=value&user_id=value 
if $month value will be null or $user_id will be null how to work here?